# PHP Default value and Print Issues

Tags: php, html, forms, printing, rating

I am currently trying to make my php, on the same page as the form, display the values correctly and calculate the overall passer rating. My calculations follow the formatting this way:

**C = ((# completions/#attempts) *100 -30)/20**

**Y= ((# yards/#attempts) -3)/4**

**T = ((#touchdowns/#attempts) *20)**

**I = 2.375 - (#interceptions/#attempts) * 35**

**Pass Rating = ((C+Y+T+I)/6) *100**

The table that holds the values from the form should have a default value of 0 and below it should print the overall rating of Poor, Good and Great depending on the passer rating.

As you see I have a few issues.
My issues are:

**The Passing Rating doesn't default to 0.**

**My Overall Rating doesn't print whether it is Poor, Good, or Great. It only prints Poor**

I was hoping someone can explain this. I have been troubleshooting it for hours now. No luck sadly. ps(overall rating printed twice to see which version I want to use)

**Also the snippet won't run the php unless you have php on your comp. Need a server to see it even with the snippet I guess**

UPDATE: I put 20 instead of 4 to divide in Y value. That fixed my calculations but not the overall rating.

SECOND UPDATE: I added the line:

```
if(($_POST['First'] != '') && ($_POST['Last'] != ''))
```

so that I can keep my defaults for the table.

**My last issues is now the Overall Rating displaying the correct label of either Poor, Good or Great**

```js
<?php

$first = "";
$last = "";
$completions = 0;
$attempts = 0;
$yards = 0;
$touchdowns = 0;
$interceptions = 0;
$TotalScores = 0;

if(isset($_POST['First'])) {
        $first = $_POST['First'];
}

if(isset($_POST['Last'])){

        $last = $_POST['Last'];
}

if(isset($_POST['completions'])) {

 $completions = $_POST['completions']; 
}
if(isset($_POST['attempts'])) {
        $attempts = $_POST['attempts'];
}

if(isset($_POST['yards'])){

        $yards = $_POST['yards'];
}

if(isset($_POST['touchdowns'])) {

 $touchdowns = $_POST['touchdowns']; 
}


if(isset($_POST['interceptions'])) {

        $interceptions = $_POST['interceptions'];
}


function rating ($com, $att, $yards, $touchd, $inter){

 //$C = 0;
 //$Y = 0;
 //$T = 0;
 //$I = 0;
 $passRating = 0;

 

 $C = ((($com /$att)*100)-30) / 20;
 $Y = (($yards/$att)-3)/4;
 $T = ($touchd/$att)*20;
 $I = 2.375 - (($inter/$att)*35);

 $passRating = (($C + $Y + $T + $I)/6)*100;

 return $passRating;
}


if(is_numeric($completions) && is_numeric($attempts) && is_numeric($yards)
    && is_numeric($touchdowns) && is_numeric($interceptions)) {

    //if(($_POST['completions'] >0) && ($_POST['attempts'] >0) && ($_POST['yards'] >0)
    //      && ($_POST['touchdowns'] >0) && ($_POST['interceptions'] >0) ){


if(($_POST['First'] != '') && ($_POST['Last'] != '')){

    $TotalScore = rating($completions, $attempts, $yards,
                            $touchdowns, $interceptions);
    //echo $TotalScore;
    if ($TotalScore < 85 && $TotalScore >0){
    $score = "Poor";
    }

    elseif($TotalScore >=85 && $TotalScore <90){
    $score = "Mediocre";
    }
    elseif ($TotalScore >=90 && $TotalScore <95){
    $score = "Good";
    }

    elseif ($score >= 95){
    $score = "Great";
    }
    }
//}
}
else {

    $score = "Invalid Input!";
    //echo $TotalScore;
}

?>
```

```css
.form-container {

 padding-right: 20px;



}

fieldset {

 width: 200px;
 height: 30px; 
 padding: 5px;


}

input {
 padding-bottom: 5px;

}



#text-container {
 margin-top: 100px;
 width: 1260px;
 height: 400px;
 background-color: white;
 text-align: left;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 border-radius: 10px;
 
}

#text-container p {

 margin-left: 30px;
 font-size: 20px;

}

#text-container h1 {

 margin-left: 30px;
 color: #4EA24E;
 padding-top: 10px;

}

#paragraph {

 position: absolute;
 width: 1350px;
 height: 600px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin-left: 500px;
 margin-top: 60px;


}


.signup {

 float: right;
 height: 600px;
 width: 500px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 background-color: blue;


}

#form-box {

 margin-top: 10px;
 width: 550px;
 height:600px;
 maring-left: 0;
 float: left;
 /*background-color: #B2D1F0;*/
 /*border-radius: 30px;*/
 /*box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;*/
}

#form-box label {

 float: left;
     width: 200px;
     text-align: right;
     margin-right: 10px;
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 margin-left: 20px;
}

#form-box input[type="text"] {

 margin-bottom: 30px;
 height: 20px;
 width: 200px;
 font-size: 15px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;

}
.numInput input[type="text"] {

        margin-bottom: 30px;
        height: 20px;
        width: 50px;
        font-size: 15px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
}
#form-box button {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 height: 35px;
 width: 100px;
 font-size: 25px;
 margin-right: 100px;
 float: right;
 background-color: #4EA24E;
 color: orange;
 border-radius: 5px;
 text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
 font-family: Rockwell, 'Courier Bold', serif

}

#form-box button:hover {

 color: gold;

}

#form-box h1{

 text-align: left;
 margin-right: 65px;
 color: #4EA24E;
 font-size: 35px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 text-shadow: 0 0 1px black;
 margin-left: 30px;
 }

#form-box h2{

 text-align: right;
 margin-right: 85px;
 color: #114611;
 }

#calcContainer {
 clear: both;
 width: 200px;
 height: 500px;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 600px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

.table {
 margin-top: 20px;

}
.table td, .table tr {
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 150px;

}
.table h3 {
 margin-top: 40px;

}
/*table {
 margin-top: 200px;
}

td , tr{
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 150px;
}
*/
span {
 margin-left: 40px;
}


#screen {


}

html {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 min-width: 960px;
 max-width: 1000px;
 background: url(bubbles.jpg) no-repeat;
 height: 100%;
 background-size: 960px 960px;
 //margin-bottom: 100px;
}



#footer {
 width:100%;
 height:100px !important;
 border-top:4px solid black;
 background-color:orange;
 //position: relative;
 //bottom: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0 auto;
 //position: fixed;
 z-index: 10;
 clear: both;
 margin-top: 500px;
 margin-left: 30px;
}
#footer-inner {
 width:80%;
 margin:0 auto 0 auto;
 height:inherit;
}

body {
 margin-bottom: 100px;
 margin-right: 30px;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

h1.name{

 /*font-family: Lato, 'Courier Bold', sanserif;*/
 font-family: 'KOMIKAX_';
 src: url(KOMIKAX_.tff);
 font-weight: bold;
 font-variant: small-caps;
 color: "red";
 margin-left: 30px;
 text-shadow: 0 0 1px black;

}

#header {
 margin-left: 30px;
 width:100%;
}

#gradient {
     height: 65px;
 /* IE 10 */
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, black 0%, orange 100%);

 /* Firefox */
     background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, black, orange); 

 /* Safari  & Chrome */
     background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top, color-stop(0, orange),color-stop(1, black)); 

 box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px black;
}



#nav1 {

list-style: none;

}

#nav2 {

list-style: none;

}

.nav a {

 text-decoration: none; /*remove underline*/
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: white;
 font-family: Rockwell, 'Courier Bold', serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 
}

.nav li {

 display: inline;
 float: left;
 padding: 10px;
 

}

.nav a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
    }
.nav a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color:  black;
 background-color:transparent;

    }
.nav a:active {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #19A3FF;
 
    }

.container {

 margin-left: 30px;
 height: 560px;
 background-color: black;
 width: 1000px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 float: left;
}

.text-left {

 float: left;
 padding-left: 30px;
}

.text-right {

 float: right;
 padding-right: 55px;
}

.text-center {

 float: center;
 margin: auto 0;
}

.MainImage {

 background-image: url(http://cdn2.sportngin.com/attachments/photo/2021/8243/football_large.jpg); 

 height: 300px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width:99.8%;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 display: block;
 border: 1px solid;
 margin-left: 30px;
 opacity: 0.9;
      filter: alpha(opacity=90); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}


h1.title {

 color: white;
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 font-size: 60px;
 font-family: Rockwell, 'Courier Bold', serif;
 font-variant: small-caps;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}



#sub {

 color: white;
 padding-left: 80px;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-family: Rockwell, 'Courier Bold', serif;
 font-variant: small-caps;
 text-shadow: 0 0 8px black;
 

}

/*.highlight {

 /*text-shadow: 0 0 10px #E6FFFF;*/
 text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,1) , 0 0 20px rgba(255,255,255,1) , 0 0 30px rgba(255,255,255,1) , 0 0 40px #ff00de , 0 0 70px #ff00de , 0 0 80px #ff00de , 0 0 100px #ff00de ;

 filter: glow(color=#E6FFFF, strength=3);
 color: red;
 

}*/

#sidebar {

 height: 1200px;
 width: 400px;
 float: left;
 background-color: #99CC99;
 margin-top: 50px;
 font-size: 25px;
 margin-right: 0;
}

#main-container {

 width: 1260px;
 height: 230px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 postion: relative;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

#main-container2 {

 width: 1260px;
 height: 230px;
 postion: relative;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 0;
  

}


#columns {

 float: left;
 width: 370px;
     height: 230px;
     background-color: #ECF2F8;
     text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin-left: 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 border: 1px solid black;


}

#columns-image {

 foat: left;
 width: 390px;
 border: 1px solid black;
     height: 230px;
  display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 18px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid black;

}

#bar-left {

 height: 230px;
 width: 30px;
 background-color: blue;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-left: 0;


}

#bar-right {

 height: 230px;
 width: 30px;
 background-color: blue;
 float: left;


}

#bullet {

 list-style-Type: none;
 padding: 0 0 4px 23px;
 background: ur(http://www.computerhope.com/arrow.gif) no-repeat left top;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>


<head>
 <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "stylesheet.css" type = "text/css">
 <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "formstylesheet.css" type = "text/css">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=80" />
</head>


<div id = "screen">




<body>


<h1 class = "name"><font color = "orange" font size = "20px"> Passer Ratings |  </font><font size = "12" font color = "#4EA24E"> Monitor Your Results to Improve!</font></h1>

 <div id = "header">
  <div id = "gradient">
   <div class = "nav">

  <!-- container-fluid gives full width container of whole viewport -->

  <div class = "container-fluid">

  <ul id = "nav1" class= "text-left">
   <li><a href = "main.html"><strong>Home</a></li>
   <li><a href = "#">About Us</a></li>
   <li><a href = "#">Teach</a></li>
   <li><a href = "#">Score Board</strong></a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul id = "nav2" class = "text-right">
   <li><a href = "#"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
  </ul>

  </div><!-- end container-fluid-->
   </div><!--end nav-->
  </div>
 </div> <!-- end header -->



 <div id = "Main">

   <div class = "MainImage">

  <h1 class = "title"> Knowing your Strengths and Weaknesses..<br></h1>
  <p id = "sub"><font color= "#4DFFFF"><strong> Makes</strong>
    </font> a great player... </p>

   </div><!-- end MainImage-->
 
  <form id ="form-box" action = 'passrating.php' method = 'post'>
  <h1>Calculate Passer Rating<br><br> 
  <h2>Submit to Review the information </h2>

  
      <label>First Name </label>
      <input type="text" name = 'First' placeholder='First'/><br/>
      <label>Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name = 'Last' placeholder='Last'/><br/>
  <label>Pass Completions</label>
      <input type="text" name = 'completions' value = 0 class = 'numInput'><br/>
  <label>Pass Attempts:</label>
                <input type="text" name = 'attempts' value = 0><br/>
                <label>Total Passing Yards:</label>
                <input type="text" name = 'yards' value = 0><br/>
                <label>Touchdowns:</label>
                <input type="text" name = 'touchdowns' value = 0><br/>
                <label>Interceptions:</label>
                <input type="text" name = 'interceptions' value = 0><br/>
  <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
  <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>

  </form>

<div class='calcContainer'>

  <table class='table' action = 'passrating.php' method = 'post'>
  <h3>Totals for Calculations</h3>
    <tr> Test Case:<?php echo "\t" .$first. "\t" .$last; ?></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pass Completions </td>
      <td width = "20px"><span value = 0><?php echo $completions; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pass Attempts </td>
      <td><span value = 0><?php echo $attempts; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total Passing Yards </td>
      <td><span value = 0><?php echo $yards; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Touchdowns </td>
      <td><span value =0><?php echo $touchdowns; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Interceptions: </td>
      <td><span value = 0 ><?php echo $interceptions; ?></td>
           </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Passing Rating: </td>
      <td><span value = 0 ><?php echo $TotalScore; ?></td>
   </table>

 <p value = " ">The Overall Rating is: <?php echo $score; ?></p>

 <p value = ""><?php echo "The Overall Rating is: " .$score. "</br>"; ?></p> 

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>


<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "stylesheet.css" type = "text/css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "formstylesheet.css" type = "text/css">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=80" />
</head>


<div id = "screen">




<body>


<h1 class = "name"><font color = "orange" font size = "20px"> Passer Ratings |  </font><font size = "12" font color = "#4EA24E"> Monitor Your Results to Improve!</font></h1>

    <div id = "header">
        <div id = "gradient">
            <div class = "nav">

        <!-- container-fluid gives full width container of whole viewport -->

        <div class = "container-fluid">

        <ul id = "nav1" class= "text-left">
            <li><a href = "main.html"><strong>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Teach</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Score Board</strong></a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id = "nav2" class = "text-right">
            <li><a href = "#"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
        </ul>

        </div><!-- end container-fluid-->
            </div><!--end nav-->
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end header -->



    <div id = "Main">

            <div class = "MainImage">

        <h1 class = "title"> Knowing your Strengths and Weaknesses..<br></h1>
        <p id = "sub"><font color= "#4DFFFF"><strong> Makes</strong>
                </font> a great player... </p>

            </div><!-- end MainImage-->

        <form id ="form-box" action = 'passrating.php' method = 'post'>
        <h1>Calculate Passer Rating<br><br> 
        <h2>Submit to Review the information </h2>


            <label>First Name </label>
            <input type="text" name = 'First' placeholder='First'/><br/>
            <label>Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name = 'Last' placeholder='Last'/><br/>
        <label>Pass Completions</label>
            <input type="text" name = 'completions' value = 0 class = 'numInput'><br/>
        <label>Pass Attempts:</label>
                <input type="text" name = 'attempts' value = 0><br/>
                <label>Total Passing Yards:</label>
                <input type="text" name = 'yards' value = 0><br/>
                <label>Touchdowns:</label>
                <input type="text" name = 'touchdowns' value = 0><br/>
                <label>Interceptions:</label>
                <input type="text" name = 'interceptions' value = 0><br/>
        <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
        <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>

        </form>

<div class='calcContainer'>

  <table class='table' action = 'passrating.php' method = 'post'>
  <h3>Totals for Calculations</h3>
    <tr> Test Case:<?php echo "\t" .$first. "\t" .$last; ?></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pass Completions </td>
      <td width = "20px"><span value = 0><?php echo $completions; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pass Attempts </td>
      <td><span value = 0><?php echo $attempts; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total Passing Yards </td>
      <td><span value = 0><?php echo $yards; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Touchdowns </td>
      <td><span value =0><?php echo $touchdowns; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Interceptions: </td>
      <td><span value = 0 ><?php echo $interceptions; ?></td>
           </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Passing Rating: </td>
      <td><span value = 0 ><?php echo $TotalScore; ?></td>
   </table>

    <p value = " ">The Overall Rating is: <?php echo $score; ?></p>

    <p value = ""><?php echo "The Overall Rating is: " .$score. "</br>"; ?></p> 

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried var_dump() just to see what actual numbers are being given to your variables? Starting from there might be a good idea as you know what your functions are working with in the first place.

Comment: ya I had to fix an issue... I didn't divide by 4 in one of the calculations... fixed the values but not the overall rating.. my .$score doesn't seem to be working correctly

Comment: Well you do have a logic error where your 'poor' and 'mediocre' if statements are. The 'poor' if statement triggers at equal to or less than 85, and the 'mediocre' if statement triggers at between & including 85 through 90. So if someone gets 85, they'll first trigger as poor, and then mediocre.

This is likely not the solution to your larger problem, however.

Comment: @AndyHall I corrected most of my issues including what you pointed out in my if statements. Now my overall Rating won't stop displaying my default for it. Now it always displays my "N/A" versus Poor, Good or Great

Comment: So you're absolutely sure your variables have values? And your pass rating variable is returning a number you think is right? Because if you're getting your base variables okay, then you might have a problem with your algorithms in your rating function.

Comment: @AndyHall I have tried echoing my $score value to troubleshoot and nothing seems to display. my $score value is based on $TotalScore and I know TotalScore has a value. Makes me confused thinking I can't assign a value with a string O.o

Comment: When troubleshooting, you might be best off with var_dump() as it let's you see everything about every variable. The only other thing I'd say is to declare score at the top with your other variables and initialise to 0.

Comment: Haven't done var_dump() before so I will look into it and I did before. I had $score = "N/A" to initialize but after I did that it never changed from N/A even after the form was run @AndyHall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to fix my issues:

```
if(is_numeric($completions) && is_numeric($attempts) && is_numeric($yards) 
&& is_numeric($touchdowns) && is_numeric($interceptions)) {

//if(($_POST['completions'] >0) && ($_POST['attempts'] >0) && ($_POST['yards'] >0)
//  && ($_POST['touchdowns'] >0) && ($_POST['interceptions'] >0) ){

if(($_POST['First'] != '') && ($_POST['Last'] != '')){  

//  $TotalScore = rating($completions, $attempts, $yards, 
//              $touchdowns, $interceptions);

 if(($_POST['completions'] <0) || ($_POST['attempts'] <0) || ($_POST['yards'] <0)
          || ($_POST['touchdowns'] <0) || ($_POST['interceptions'] <0) ){

      $score =  "</br></br><strong>Invalid Input!</strong></br>Please Provide non-Negative Numbers.";
 }

//echo $TotalScore; 
else {

    $TotalScore = rating($completions, $attempts, $yards,
                            $touchdowns, $interceptions);

    if($TotalScore < 0) {

     $score =  "</br></br><strong>Invalid Results</strong></br>Please review over your scores.          The Passing Rating shouldn't be negative.";

    }


    if($TotalScore > 0 && $TotalScore <85){
        $score = "Poor";
    }

    elseif($TotalScore >=85 && $TotalScore <90){
        $score = "Mediocre";
    }
    elseif ($TotalScore >=90 && $TotalScore <95){
        $score = "Good";
    }

    elseif ($TotalScore >= 95){
        $score = "Great";
    }
}
//}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use my tiny library [ValueResolver](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) in this case, for example:

```
$value = ValueResolver::resolve('', 'default value'); // returns 'default value' because first argument is empty
```

and don't forget to use namespace `use LapaLabs\ValueResolver\Resolver\ValueResolver;`

There are also ability to typecasting, for example if your variable's value should be `integer`, so use this:

```
$id = ValueResolver::toInteger('6 apples', 1); // returns 6
$id = ValueResolver::toInteger('There are no apples', 1); // returns 1 (used default value)
```

Check the [docs](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) for more examples